# CGImageCreateWithImageInRect

Tags: objective-c, crop, cgimageref

I am trying to create a simple cropping app. I have a view overlayed on a UIImage and I want to crop a new image out of only the part of the UIImage where the view is overlayed. I used the code

```
CGRect cropRect = _cropView.frame;
UIImage *cropImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
CGImageRef cropped = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([cropImage CGImage], cropRect);
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cropped];
self.imageView.image = croppedImage;
```

but it resulted in an unexpected image that seemed very zoomed in and not what I wanted. How can I crop a new image from the image behind the view?

Answer (score 0):

A `CGImage` deals with pixels, not "points" (the abstract measurement unit of UIKit). When the crop view's `contentScaleFactor` is larger than 1, its pixel dimensions will be larger than its point dimensions. So, to get a crop rect that corresponds to the pixels, you need to multiply all of the coordinates and dimensions of the view's `frame` by its `contentScaleFactor`.

```
CGRect cropRect = _cropView.frame;
cropRect.origin.x *= _cropView.contentScaleFactor;
cropRect.origin.y *= _cropView.contentScaleFactor;
cropRect.size.width *= _cropView.contentScaleFactor;
cropRect.size.height *= _cropView.contentScaleFactor;
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not fix the problem. The image is still way too zoomed in and also rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise

Answer (score 0):

May be this help you,

```
// Create new image context
CGSize size = _cropView.frame.size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);

// Create rect for image
CGRect rect = _cropView.frame;

// Draw the image into the rect
[existingImage drawInRect:rect];

// Saving the image, ending image context
UIImage * newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but this ended up not working either. I am still very confused by my output